# Ошибка в мобильном по

Tags: ionic

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Доброго времени суток, хочу подключить ionic приложение к своему wordpress сайту, вроде все прописал, а тут такое нет соединение с интернетом

так-же заходим на стр.регистрации а там выходит уже ошибка подходящий маршрут для url и метода запроса не найден

не знаю что делать, прям вообще не могу понять

Comment: Как происходит подключение в коде - мало информации даете, возможно вы, что - то не правильно настроили.

Comment: createAccessToken:function(user){
                    var token = '';
                    $http.post( serviceBase + 'wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token', {
                        username: user.username,
                        password: user.password
                    } )
                    .then( function( response ) {
                        console.log(response.data);   
                        token = response.data.token;
                        Token.set(token);
                    } )

Comment: эх, я подразумевал, что вы юзаете js-ajax. Вопрос? Это приложение на Java? Попробуйте new Java.